# Difficulty understanding recursion puzzle

Tags: c++, recursion

I am trying to print the steps leading to the answer but not getting anywhere. Please refer to this image:

[image]

I am able to check if the given problem is solvable or not:

```
bool Solvable(int a[], int index, int target, int sz, int b[]) {
    static int b_ind = 0;
    if (target == 0 && index == sz-1)
        return true;
    if (index >= sz || index < 0)
        return false;
    int u_ind = index+a[index];
    int d_ind = index-a[index];
    bool u_y = Solvable(a,u_ind,a[u_ind],sz,b);
    if (u_y) {
        b[b_ind++] = u_ind;
        return u_y; }
    else {
        bool d_y = Solvable(a,d_ind,a[d_ind],sz,b);
        if (d_y) {
            b[b_ind++] = d_ind;
            return d_y; }
    }
}
```

but am not able to print the sequence of indexes visited for a correct solution.

Comment: Could you paste up the entire problem without using a link please? (As they tend to break). Also do detail what you've achieved so far.

Comment: I am able to check if the given problem is solvable or not: 
bool Solvable(int a[], int index, int target, int sz, int b[]) {
    static int b_ind = 0;
    if (target == 0 && index == sz-1)
        return true;
    if (index >= sz || index < 0)
        return false;

    int u_ind = index+a[index];
    int d_ind = index-a[index];

    bool u_y = Solvable(a,u_ind,a[u_ind],sz,b);
    if (u_y) {
        b[b_ind++] = u_ind;
        return u_y;
    }
    else {
        bool d_y = Solvable(a,d_ind,a[d_ind],sz,b);
        if (d_y)
            b[b_ind++] = d_ind;
        return d_y;
    }
}

Comment: but am not able to print the sequence of indexes visited for a correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

2 things to do :

1. When your criterion is reached eg `if (target == 0 && index == sz-1)`, display the `b` variable. `b`  is where your store the explored path right ?
2. when Solvable(...) returns `false` you must decrement `b_ind`

NB: your code is a bit suspicious since the last `if` does not have any else ; this is missing :

```
        if (d_y) {
            b[b_ind++] = d_ind;
            return d_y;
        } /* the following block is missing */
        else 
        {
            b_ind--;
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: That;s a mistake. } should have been above return in d_y block. 
Yes, b is for storing the path.
However, this approach won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot print the indices on your way because you don't know in advance whether you will find a solution or not. So what you have to do is, in your recursive calls, pass on a list (the "path") of positions visited. Make sure you don't change existing paths but you actually create copies.

Also, you might want to go on searching after having found a first solution, sometimes there's more than one.

A catch is that you might loop forever depending on the input puzzle. That's why it's actually beneficial to have the path because it allows you to detect loops.

In executable pseudo-code (they call it Python) it's something like:

```python
def puzzle(lst):
    def solve(pos, path):
        if 0 <= pos < length:   # position is inside puzzle
            if pos not in path: # we've already been here; prevent looping
                val = lst[pos]
                newpath = path + [pos] # newpath is a *copy* of path with pos appended
                if val == 0:    # we've found one solution
                    print(newpath)
                else:
                    solve(pos-val, newpath)
                    solve(pos+val, newpath)
    length = len(lst)
    solve(0, [])

puzzle([3, 6, 4, 1, 3, 4, 2, 5, 3, 0])
```

For your example this yields:

```python
[0, 3, 2, 6, 8, 5, 9]
[0, 3, 4, 1, 7, 2, 6, 8, 5, 9]
[0, 3, 4, 7, 2, 6, 8, 5, 9]
```